# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'props')

Tags: reactjs

In my react JS web app. I am getting below error from the following code.

This code is taken from:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-react

```
import React from "react";
import { Map, InfoWindow, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper } from 'google-maps-react';

const Googlemap = () => {
        return (
                <Map google={this.props.google} zoom={14}>
                        <Marker onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
                                name={'Current location'} />
                        <InfoWindow onClose={this.onInfoWindowClose}>
                                <div>
                                        <h1>{this.state.selectedPlace.name}</h1>

                                </div>
                        </InfoWindow>
                </Map>
        );
}
export default GoogleApiWrapper({
        apiKey: ("MY KEY")
})(Googlemap)
```

[image]

Please advise

Regards

Comment: How is this related to Angular? Also generally not a good idea to post API keys. You don't define `props` anywhere, like in the parameter list to `Googlemap`. And functional components don't have a `this`.

Comment: Many thanks David. I have removed key. Thanks for pointing it out. Angular I have added as Angular guy can easily help with React. What I should write in place of this in this functional components.

Comment: ... include `props` in the parameter list, and remove `this`.

Comment: Means my code should be <Map google={props.google} zoom={14}>. I will try tomorrow morning.

Comment: The `<Googlemap>` component needs to have a `props` parameter (or it can be destructured, e.g., `const Googlemap = ({ google }) ...`

Comment: I will try with below code tomorrow. const Googlemap = () => {
        return (
                <Map google={google} zoom={14}>
                        <Marker onClick={this.onMarkerClick}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237335/discussion-between-d-b-and-dave-newton).

Comment: No, that isn't what I wrote. The `<Googlemap>` component either a) must have a `props` parameter (`const Googlemap = (props) ...`) and you can refer to the property as `props.google`, or b) can be destructured in the params (`const Googlemap = ({ google }) ...`) and referred to by `google`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sample page you provide, the following code is presented:

```
import {Map, InfoWindow, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper} from 'google-maps-react';
 
export class MapContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Map google={this.props.google} zoom={14}>
 
        <Marker onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
                name={'Current location'} />
 
        <InfoWindow onClose={this.onInfoWindowClose}>
            <div>
              <h1>{this.state.selectedPlace.name}</h1>
            </div>
        </InfoWindow>
      </Map>
    );
  }
}
 
export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: (YOUR_GOOGLE_API_KEY_GOES_HERE)
})(MapContainer)
```

Notice that `MapContainer` is a `class` which `extends Component`, which is why `this.props` is a valid reference.

In your code, you use the functional style of defining `MapContainer` (you use the name `Googlemap`), which is valid, but needs to be handled a little bit differently. As other users have pointed out, you need to explicitly parameterize `const Googlemap = (props) => ...` or [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) as in `const Googlemap = ({google, ...props}) => ...` and then use `props` (or `google` in the destructured version) explicitly instead of `this.props`.

However, it appears that `GoogleApiWrapper` is providing some other things, e.g. `onMarkerClick` and `onInfoWindowClose`, so you're probably a lot better off following their example and using the old Component class style instead of the new functional style for your component.

Comment: Thanks, I will make some changes today and come back to you. Regards